# C#: Problem calling method inside a string property setter

Tags: c#, file, properties, methods, setter

I have a string property that defines a filename for an xml file.  When the user inputs this filename into the property, I have the setter calling a parseXml() function immediatly after setting 'fileName = value' to populate a dataTable with the data from the XML file so it displays in the designer.  For some reason, when I have this function call in the property setter, the setter ends up getting called every twice every time I change the property, with the 2nd time being an empty string which causes an error.  Why is it doing this?

```
public String FileName
{
    get { return fileName; }
    set 
    {
        fileName = value;
        parseXmlFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code - both the property and where it's used.

Comment: Without showing us some code, your guess is as good as mine (actually, yours will probably be better.)

Comment: We can't possibly know without seeing any code. I suggest you put a breakpoint in the property and look at the stack trace each time it's called.

Comment: Did anyone mention that code should be posted?

Comment: the parse function is long, and the machine the code is on is offline so I can't copy and paste it into this window, but I double checked and it's not assigning the fileName anywhere in that method.  The reason I asked is because I was wondering if there is some reason in .Net why this would happen when calling a method inside a property.

Comment: A side note, this goes against .NET standards.  In general, setting properties should have little overhead and not contain too much logic or computations inside. I would have put this as LoadXmlFile(string FileName). A method implies am operation which may change the internal state of the object and might perform heavier processing.

Comment: Can you post parseXmlFile() also, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: it shouldn't.
More helpful: maybe you cause the second call yourself? Set the debugger on the setter and the second time it is called, inspect the call stack.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question.  I just wanted to make sure it was a problem in my code and not a conflict in .NET before I wasted too much time debugging when I should be refactoring.

Answer (score 9):

My initial guess would be that something in parseXml() is calling that setter again. What happens if you remove the call to parseXml()? Have you tried debugging and stepping through the code as it is running to see what exactly is calling the setter the second time?

If you slap a breakpoint on `filename = value;` and hit it, what does the callstack window show you?

Comment: The first time the property is called, the fileName and 'value' values are the correct input from the user.  The parseXml function is executed with no problems.  Immediatly after, it goes through the setter again and now 'value' is the empty string so it resets the fileName to the emptyString and executes parseXml() with an empty fileName and then it causes an error.

Comment: And what does the callstack look like on that second write? From where was the setter called?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the set {...}. When it stops there, check teh call stack. You need to figure out who is making teh second request.

Answer (score 0):

As a complete aside to the problem you're having, putting expensive IO operations behind property setters is a little off kilter.

If you want to open up a file and parse stuff etc it would be better to have a separate method named appropriately that does the IO and sets this property (filename) at the end when the method successfully completed its work.

Comment: Not really an answer to his problem - I said the same thing as a comment on his question.